# Facebook Connect Statistics

Tags: facebook

All,

A client is asking for Facebook Connect statistical data. Specifically, how many people have shared a link to their wall.

I have a Facebook app setup but I am having trouble interpreting the statistical data. Do Facebook apps collect this data, or can anyone think of any way of gleaning this data from the past month, from server logs or something? For instance, can I look at the logs for xd_receiver.htm and see usage patterns from that, or something?

Answer (score 0):

nope, currently there are no any API methods to get such kind of statistics. you have to collect it manually.

ps: xd_receiver is used once user is in connect process, nothing after.